# How to upgrade mysql-client mysql-server on a LAMP stack?

Tags: upgrade, mysql

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade -y

The following packages have been kept back: mysql-client mysql-server

sudo apt-get upgrade mysql-client mysql-server

The following packages have unmet dependencies:  mysql-common : Conflicts: mysql-client-8.0 but 8.0.34-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 is to be installed
Conflicts: mysql-client-core-8.0 but 8.0.34-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 is to be installed  mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-8.0 but it is not installable E: Broken packages
```

I have also tried upgrading them separately without luck.

Thanks